# How do I print integers from a const unsorted array in descending order which I cannot create a copy of?

Tags: c, logic

For example if given `{3, 0, 9, 99, 1}`, I would want it to be 
`{99, 9 ,3, 1, 0}`. I have tried creating another array store the value as I find the next maximum one each time but I am at a loss to implement. (new C programmer). Any help is appreciated, would like to try and solve this in O(n^2)

Comment: Why do you need to create another array ?  Why not simply scan, as you say, for the next maximum value and print it ?  [Dealing with two or more equal values I leave as an exercise.]  For each of the n values you print, you will scan all n values (in general) giving the O(n^2) you want/expect.  [Alternatively, are you allowed to construct an auxiliary array of indexes, which you could sort ?]

Comment: How do I find the next largest element each time? Would that not go into an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you claim, I don't think the problem is one of implementing a solution. If it was, you would have specified what you had trouble implementing. But you didn't, so I think it's a problem coming up with the algorithm itself.

You asked for a solution requiring O(1) memory and O(N^2) time. That's actually larger than required. By sorting the array in-place and then printing it, a solution requiring O(1) memory and O(N log N) time is [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

But let's assume you wanted a non-destructive solution, meaning one doesn't modify the input array. The following is such a solution requiring O(1) memory and O(N^2) time:

1. Set max = maximum integer.
2. Set count = 0.
3. While count is less than the number of elements in the array,

   1. Set next = minimum integer.
   2. For every element of the array,

      1. If the element's value is equal to max,

         1. Print the element's value.
         2. Increment count.
      2. Else,

         1. If the element's value is larger than next and less than max,

            1. Set next to the element's value
   3. Set max = next.

Each of these steps are trivial to implement in C.